# Using PyQuery and Gadget selector to extract URLs from a Website

Tags: python, python-requests, pyquery

I have code that only works partially:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests

url = SAMPLE_URL.com 
content = requests.get(url).content
doc = pq(content)

Latest_Report = doc(".head+ .post .heading")

Latest_Report.text()
```

I am able to get the Text element with this. But I want to use the URL available here.

```
print(Latest_Report)
```

What is the best way to get the href:

```
<a class="heading" href="URL_WANTED">ABC’s September Construction Backlog Indicator Dips, Yet Contractors Remain Confident</a>
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not allowing me to post correct URL. Asking question is much harder now.

Comment: Works. Where can I find documentation for this ?

Comment: Updated in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Latest_Report.attr('href')` [to access the `href` attribute](https://pyquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/attributes.html) of the element.